# Transactions for typescript like clojure refs?

Tags: typescript, clojure, consistency

Is there any similar transaction like concept in Typescript (or in its ecosystem) like Clojure's ref to maintain consistency?

Comment: The term you're looking for is *software transactional memory*. A [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQ5Kr8uM0yR9cyeEjcOyaF9jiQ_3Q%3A1568380967787&source=hp&ei=J5h7XdncLay8ggeMrIS4BQ&q=software+transactional+memory+typescript&btnK=Google+Search&oq=sitecore+cms+bundle+files&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1531.1531..2571...0.0..0.147.249.0j2......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....10..35i362i39.O2pv-XP4sVY&ved=0ahUKEwiZjNKz8s3kAhUsnuAKHQwWAVcQ4dUDCAc&uact=5) says likely not. Nor is that surprising: Javascript as a single-threaded language doesn't need it nearly as badly.

Comment: last time I checked typescript didn't do `state` at all/in any other way than js. You do know about [clojurescript](https://clojurescript.org/)?

Comment: An STM is really only feasible with immutable structures unless all the types in the entire language have support for "undoing" actions, or constant deep copying is acceptable. I'd just use clojurescript if you want STM.